# Why does struct.pack have such high variability in performance?

Tags: python, performance, struct

I get the following result when testing the performance of `struct.pack`:

```
In [3]: %timeit pack('dddd', 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
The slowest run took 578.59 times longer than the fastest. This could
mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
1000000 loops, best of 3: 197 ns per loop
```

Why is the slowest run 578 times slower? Is pack doing some internal caching, or is this the result of some sort of CPU-level caching, or something else?

Comment: Is your result repeatable? I can't reproduce it.

Comment: @zch: I can replicate the results on Python 2.7.6.

Comment: Yes, it's doing internal caching.  The format argument to `struct.pack` gets turned into a `Struct` instance; recent `Struct` instances are cached for possible future use.

Comment: Can't reproduce on either Python 2.7.6. or Python 3.4.0.

Comment: I am running Python 2.7.6 on Linux, and for me it's repeatable

Comment: source link: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/0afaeb974b27b6eeeaf3e5d27d4a733542c21b2f/Modules/_struct.c#L2006-L2035

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce this with Mac OS X and Python 2.7.9.

Comment: @MarkDickinson: better link to the official Python project mercurial repository: https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/05b96af72805/Modules/_struct.c for the Python 2.7 branch tip.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Maybe.  I find it easier to browse on GitHub, and I like being able to highlight lines and segments of the code.

Comment: 2.7.6 revision: https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3a1db0d2747e/Modules/_struct.c

Comment: It seems like we have an answer to this question...does someone want to add it as an answer that I can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IPython profiler is spot on. The result is indeed cached (at least in some python versions). For example in python 2.7.6 you can find the relevant code [here](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3a1db0d2747e/Modules/_struct.c#l1795) where the `cache_struct` function is defined.

This function looks up the cache to see if, recently, the given format was used and returns the relevant `Struct` instance instead of creating a new one (which seems relatively expensive).

You can see that it is used in the [`pack`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3a1db0d2747e/Modules/_struct.c#l1869) function (and others).

---

This content was posted in comments but deserves to be an answer.